# Complex Number Inequality $|2+z|\leq 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

If I have a complex number $z = a + ib$, how do you interpret the inequality

$|2+z|\leq 2$?

I believe the answer is a circle in the complex plane, but where I am getting confused is understanding the inequality due to the use of imaginary numbers on the left hand side and no imaginary numbers on the right hand side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $|2+z|$ is a real number

Comment: $|z-(-2)|$ is the distance of the complex number $z$ from the complex number $-2+0i$.

Comment: The absolute value of an imaginary number is a real number.  BTW complex numbers don't have order so you can only use $\le$ with real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a disc, centered at point $-2$ on the complex plane and with radius $2$. The non existence of imaginary numbers in the inequality is only natural: there is no "order" in $\mathbb{C}$, you cannot compare two complex numbers. No such relation is defined. If you want to get some more intuition on that stuff, try expressing complex numbers as numbers of $\mathbb{R}^2$. How would you write this equation for $z=x+iy$? simply as $\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}\leq2$, which is precisely the object we described: a disc center at point $(-2,0)$ and of radius $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Write this as $|z-(-2)| \leq 2$. In that case, this would mean that the distance of your point z from the point (-2,0) is always less than or equal to 2. Or, make the circle centered at (-2,0) radius 2, this gives you all points on the boundary and inside the circle.

Comment: You meant *less* than or equal to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$|2+z|\leq 2 \iff |z-(-2)|\leq 2 \iff d(z, -2)\leq 2$$

That is the closed ball with center at $-2$ and radius $2$

Answer (score 1):

I will ake for granted that you know the equation of the circle.

We know that $z=x+iy$, hence collecting real and imaginary parts together we have
$$\left|[x-(-2)]+iy\right|\leq2$$
or

$$(x+2)^2+y^2\leq4$$

Clearly this represents a closed disk of radius $2$ with a centre $(-2,0)$.